# Comparing convergence of hill and pickands estimators in R

Tags: r, estimation, mse

i am working on extreme value theory, i used commands hillplot and pickandsplot of the package evmix to plot the hill and pickands estimators and get the threshold u and the number of excess k.

```
library(evmix)
hillplot(claims$cost)
pickandsplot(claims$cost)
```

Now i want to plot the graph of the error of estimation with respect to k/n where n is the length of the vector claims$cost (k/n tends to 0 when n is too large).
Can someone help me solve this task please ?

Comment: The code as posted gives `Error in quantile(data[data > 0], 0.9, na.rm = TRUE) :   object 'claims' not found`.

Comment: this is because i didn't give you the dataframe